C# Problem with Windows 11 number parsing
I need help with number parsing. I'm using double.TryParse() method to convert a string to a double. It's working on Windows 10, but not working on Windows 11. (with .net Framework4.8 and .net8)
I tried to parse with French culture. In France we use spaces for thousands.
The next code is working in Windows 10 but not in Windows 11
bool isParsed = double.TryParse("12 000,12", NumberStyles.Any, new CultureInfo("fr-FR"), out double result);

I expected 'isParsed' to be true but it was false.
Currently it's working on Windows 10 but not on Windows 11
Has anybody encountered this before ?
Thank you

Did you try looking at the properties of the NumberFormatInfo of that CultureInfo? Are they what you expect them to be and the same in both cases? BTW, am I missing something or did you just post the same code twice?

Can't confirm. isParsed is true for me on Win11.

Thank you @jmcilhinney for your response.
Sorry for posting the same code twice, but it's my first time.
I have already looked at the NumberFormatInfo and it returned this (the NumberGroupSeparator is a space as expected, there both the same):
NumberGroupSeparator: " "
I built it on Windows 11 and ran it on Windows 10, the TryParse returned true.
I built it on Windows 10 and ran it on Windows 11, the TryParse returned false.

Please, inspect var format = new CultureInfo("fr-FR").NumberFormat; and then format.NumberGroupSeparator and format.NumberDecimalSeparator which should be space ' ' and comma ','

No repro with Console.WriteLine(double.Parse("12 000,123",CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR")));. I get 12000.123 as expected. This has nothing to do with Windows, which is the OS used by all European businesses for 30+ years. Had there been such a problem it would be fixed back in the 1990s

No repro with double.Parse("12 000,123",NumberStyles.Any,CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR")) either

Windows 11 isn't new either - it's already 3 years old and used in all new business PCs and servers in Europe. Had there been any issues with Windows 11, we'd know. Windows 10 itself is 9 years old and reaches end of support in 1 year.

Why the complexity you state in checking this by building on one system and executing on the other? What happens in the simplest of cases building on one system and running on that system in a defined framework you then state here? Then we have the chance to actually check something if there is a real problem hidden.

It's not a complexity, it was to eliminate an option that the problem could be in the build.
I know Windows 11 is 3 years old.
@DmitryBychenko , I inspected and it was format.NumberGroupSeparator = ' ' and format.NumberDecimalSeparator = ','

Could there be any other difference in setup between the machines that are running Windows 10 and 11? In any case, if you turn off "Just my code" in Tools->Options->Debugging, you should be able to step into the library code to see exactly where it is failing
